# Change the CSS of span div on focus of the input div using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to change the  background image of a span div on the focus of the input type. I have tried to change with appropriate parent classes but it is not working for me. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code.

```css
.enq-form-section input[name='treat-cat']:hover .enq-form-section .enq-form .tc-img {
  background: #ccc !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <span class="tc-img"></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Treatment Category" name="treat-cat">
</div>
```

Comment: Your selector is looking for a class of enq-form-section with a child input(called treat-cat) with a child of .enq-form-section with a child of .eng-form with a child of .tc-img. If these are meant to be multiple selectors then you need to comma separate them

Comment: This is not possible by `css`. You need to use Javascript.

Comment: You cannot reverse select in CSS, you can only select from the element onward and downwards, so if you have `<input><span></span>` you can have it work by using `input:focus + span` or `input:focus ~ span`

Comment: well i have tried with the <code>.enq-form-section input[name='treat-cat']:hover +.tc-img{background: #ccc !important;} </code>

But it is also not working for me. i just want to change the background image of a span tag on focus of the input tag.

Answer (score 6):

Can you change the order in which the `span` and the `input` elements are written? If so, it would be so easy. Here's an example.

```css
.form-control:hover + .tc-img,
.form-control:focus + .tc-img {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Treatment Category" name="treat-cat">
  <span class="tc-img">SOME CONTENT IN HERE</span>
</div>
```

#### Info

CSS makes it impossible to select previous elements or parent elements. [It does it for a reason](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors).

If you can't change the markup then you will have to use JavaScript to target the previous element.

Assuming you had jQuery, you would do something as follows.

```
jQuery(".form-control")
.on("focus", function(){
    // set background color on focus
    $(this).prev().css("backgroundColor","tomato");
})
.on("blur", function(){
    // remove background color on blur
    $(this).prev().css("backgroundColor","none");
});
```

Comment: Hey Thanks it works for me ...I just change the positions as of span and div and it works...Thanks a lot for the suggestion.. :) ..!!

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer as accepted whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand the css with such a small amount of html provided.  What I can tell you though is that what you are attempting to do cannot be done with css.  When you use hover states, they will only work on either the item that is being hovered on, or it's children.  You cannot put a hover state on an element and then try to edit it's parents or siblings.

What you are trying to do needs to be done through javascript.  Try using a mouseOver event with the value of a function that changes the background image of the span.

onmouseover reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Comment: thank you for the suggestion i also thought to use the java script but then i change the positions of the span and div and it works for me as suggested by Praveen Puglia. :)